# Running trough every instance of a muti-layer object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object that contains the following object template:

```
0:{
  id: 1,
  name: Name 1
  children: 0:{
    id: 2,
    name: Name 2
    children: {}
  },
  1:{
    id: 3,
    name: Name 3
    children: {}
  }
},
1:{
  id: 4,
  name: Name 4
  children: 0:{
    id: 5,
    name: Name 5
    children: {}
  }
},
```

However as you can see every "children" key can also have an exact copy of an object, an so can the children of these children and so on. How can I convert every instance of "children", including the children inside the children and so on, into an array of objects like the example below?

```
0:{
  id: 1,
  name: Name 1
  children: [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: Name 2
    children: {}
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: Name 3
    children: {}
  }
 ]
},
1:{
  id: 4,
  name: Name 4
  children: [
   {
    id: 5,
    name: Name 5
    children: {}
   }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Your ``children`` keys aren't valid. Did you mean to make them an object?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
function flatObject(arg) {
  const result = [];
  const goTo = (o, index = 0) => {
      
    // If no more objects, return
    if (typeof o[index] === "undefined")
      return;
          
    const e = o[index];
        
    // Push this object
    result.push({ id: e.id, name: e.name });
        
    // goto childrens and append them
    goTo(e.children);
        
    // Goto next item
    goTo(o, index + 1);  
  }
      
  // Call function
  goTo(arg);
      
  return result;
}
```

It uses a recursive function to go through each item, and it goes through each `children` key in order to append them in the `result` array.

### EDIT FOR MODIFIED QUESTION

What you are looking for is the `Object.entries()` method, that according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

> The **`Object.entries()`** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property `[key, value]` pairs.

```
function flatObject(arg) {
 
  // Iterate all
  Object.keys(arg).forEach(key => {
    
    const ObjectToArray = (o) => {
      // Convert children to array
      o.children = Object.entries(o.children).map(e => e[1]);
      
      // Convert children of children
      o.children.forEach(child => ObjectToArray(child));
    };
    
    // Push childrens
    ObjectToArray(arg[key]);
  });
      
  return arg;
}
```

Comment: i think i might have phrased my question in the wrong manner. your code works but it is not what i was looking for since it turns everything into one huge array instead and i was looking into turning only the children keys into object arrays. i shall correct the OP

Comment: the question has been adjusted

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man ahh ok, now I guess I got it!